# Best practice for handling worm URLs

Tags: apache, http

We've been getting request (from worms?) of the form

```
http://www.example.com/MSOffice/cltreq.asp?...
http://www.example.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?...
```

What is the best practice for dealing with these?

I've considered either returning a 404 or trying to terminate the connection while leaving it open on the other end.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just return a GONE on stuff like that, so that it doesn't show up in my error_log.